# Workflow state in Sitecore is blank when you create and save a datasource from experience editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

So here is the step to replicate.

Create a blank page, 
Open Experience Editor and add a component that needs a datasource.
Select create a new datasource in the popup window.
Save the page in experience editor
Open the datasource in the Content editor and take a look at the workflow state section. It will be blank instead of having the initial workflow state.

This only happens for non admin users.
Creating a new datasource directly in Content Editor (not Experience Editor) works fine.

** Note that when experience editor creates the datasource, if you go to Content Editor and open the item, the workflow state will be there. It is after you save the page in experience editor that the worflow state is set as null.

Answer (score 0):

So after 5 days debugging Sitecore code and pipelines I found the issue.

**The enableWorflow="true" attribute was missing in the site definitions.**

The code that was causing the issue was the .Lock step in the SaveUI pipeline.

Comment: That said, We should really push Sitecore to open the code or at least distribute the pdb. There are things that only debugging can tell you what is going wrong. No text book or course will help you here.

Comment: Can you tell where exactly it is looking for enableWorkflow in dlls?